# Spark only working with python 2

Tags: linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, apache-spark

Beginner to Spark here.

```
uname -a
```

Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.82-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I've downloaded the default Spark at http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

I want to use it with Python3.
I've added followings lines to my `.bashrc`:

```
export SPRK_HOME=/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

And just to test, I've launched python examples at 
    /home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/python
using following command lines

```
. /home/rictus/.bashrc
cd /home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/python
spark-submit pi.py
```

Spark launch and stop with a `stacktrace` coming from python :

```
rictus:~/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/python$ spark-submit pi.py 
16/11/22 22:51:49 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/22 22:51:50 WARN Utils: Your hostname, debian resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface eth0)
16/11/22 22:51:50 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 2]16/11/22 22:51:53 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 143, in main
    importlib.invalidate_caches()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'invalidate_caches'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/11/22 22:51:53 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 143, in main
    importlib.invalidate_caches()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'invalidate_caches'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/11/22 22:51:53 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 2]16/11/22 22:51:53 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/python/pi.py", line 43, in 
    count = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, n + 1), partitions).map(f).reduce(add)
  File "/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 802, in reduce
  File "/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 776, in collect
  File "/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 143, in main
    importlib.invalidate_caches()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'invalidate_caches'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1873)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1886)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1913)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:911)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rictus/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 143, in main
    importlib.invalidate_caches()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'invalidate_caches'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm confused. The file `pi.py` seems to not be Python2-specific.

I don't know what to do with this part of the `stacktrace`:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'invalidate_caches'

In my `.bashrc` file, if I change `PYSPARK_PYTHON` from `python3` to `python2`, everything is working fine.

Is my Spark compile to only work with Python2? It seems silly to me. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Spark doesn't support Python 3 releases before 3.4. You should update your Python installation to a more recent one.